# Is there a list of branches that have been checked out recently in Git?

Tags: git

I get quite tired of having to type out branch names just to change between a branch and master (or another branch) when I need to pull down master and merge it into the branch I'm working on.

I'd like to create a bash script that will checkout the branch I had checked out before the branch I currently have checked out

So if I have two branches `master` and `branch-1`

```
git checkout master (initial branch) 
git checkout branch-1 (do work on branch-1, but need to merge master changes into branch-1)
git checkout master
git pull (pull master changes) (current branch is master, previous branch is branch-1)
git checkout branch-1 <-- replace this command with a command `git lastbranch` that checks out the branch I had open before this branch
```

Basically I'm just looking for a list of my recent checked out branches, starting with my last branch

So if I've checked out master, and before that I had branch-1 checked out the list will look like

```
master
branch-1
... etc
```

Does any functionality exist?

Answer (score 5):

`git checkout` (or `git switch` in Git 2.23 and later) has a shorthand syntax for "previously checked out branch":

```
@{-1}
```

means "the branch checked out one ago", with:

```
@{-2}
```

meaning "the branch checked out two ago", and so on.  A `-` by itself:

```
git checkout -
```

means the same as `@{-1}`, for short.

(There is not a convenient way to *list* these, though.)

#### That said, you're probably doing too much work

You don't *need* to update your `master` if you are not using it.

Suppose you're working on branch `feature` and someone has made new `master` commits over at `origin` and you wish to merge or rebase using them.

You *can* do this:

```
# make sure everything is committed
$ git checkout master
$ git pull               # runs git fetch and then git merge
$ git checkout -         # back to feature
$ git merge master
```

but you can do this instead:

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/master
```

If you use a rebase workflow, this is:

```
$ git fetch
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Note the complete lack of `git checkout` steps.  We don't need to update `master`; in fact, we don't even need `master` at all and can run `git branch -d master` to get it out of the way entirely.

Comment: Learned so much from your answer here, I'll mark it as correct when the timer allows me to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To checkout the previously checked-out branch, you can use **dash**: `git checkout -`.

The same thing applies to other system commands, like `cd`.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know this existed. Makes my life easier, cheers.

Comment: Note that `cd -` is built in to the shell. Not all shells may implement it (but probably almost all do these days). Meanwhile Git's `git checkout -` is built in to Git. It was new in a very old Git, around 1.6 or 1.7, as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog`, [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

This shows a history of all the different refs (branches, tags, etc) that HEAD has pointed to. This includes every time you've checked out a different branch, commit, etc.

[image: git-reflog]